# Why is this algorithm O(nlogn)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm reading a book on algorithm analysis and have found an algorithm which I don't know how to get the time complexity of, although the book says that it is `O(nlogn)`.

Here is the algorithm:

```
sum1=0; 
for(k=1; k<=n; k*=2) 
  for(j=1; j<=n; j++) 
    sum1++;
```

Comment: *i don't know how to get the time complexity of,*  Take a pencil and a sheet of paper.  Let `n=1`, now become the computer and work through the algorithm.  Take another sheet of paper, let `n=2`, be the computer again.  Repeat for a few more small values of `n`, then one or two large ones.  Understanding will come.

Comment: Why can't you answer this, what are you missing exactly ?

Comment: Who upvotes such questions?

Comment: @xenteros Confession: I upvoted this question, though I see no reason to accept any of the answers below in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a bit of mathematical detail...

Let `a` be the number of times the outer loop `for(k=1; k<=n; k*=2)` runs. Then this loop will run `2^a` times (Note the loop increment `k*=2`). So we have `n = 2^a`. Solve for `a` by taking base 2 log on both sides, then you will get `a = log_2(n)`

Since the inner loop runs `n` times, total is `O(nlog_2(n))`.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the easiest way to convince yourself of the `O(n*lgn)` running time is to run the algorithm on a sheet of paper.  Consider what happens when n is 64.  Then the outer loop variable `k` would take the following values:

```
1 2 4 8 16 32 64
```

The `log_2(64)` is 6, which is the number of terms above plus one.  You can continue this line of reasoning to conclude that the outer loop will take `O(lgn)` running time.

The inner loop, which is completely independent of the outer loop, is `O(n)`.  Multiplying these two terms together yields `O(lgn*n)`.

Comment: log_2(64) is 6. Number of elements - 1

Answer (score 6):

In your first loop `for(k=1; k<=n; k*=2)`, variable `k` reaches the value of `n` in `log n` steps since you're doubling the value in each step.

The second loop `for(j=1; j<=n; j++)` is just a linear cycle, so requires `n` steps.

Therefore, total time is `O(nlogn)` since the loops are nested.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @qwerty's answer, if `a` is the number of times the outer loop runs:
    `k` takes values `1, 2, 4, ..., 2^a` and `2^a <= n`
    Taking log on both sides: `log_2(2^a) <= log_2(n)`, i.e. `a <= log_2(n)`

So the outer loop has a upper bound of `log_2(n)`, i.e. it cannot run more than `log_2(n)` times.